# Sprite sheet animation vs GIF animation

Tags: qt, animation, sprite, pyside, gif

I've done a little research and found how to play an animated GIF using QMovie [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/476999/play-animated-gif-files-with-pyside).  I haven't been able to find much about playing a sprite sheet animation in PySide.  I found [this example](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2010/07/sprite-animation-from-sprite-sheet-in.html), but I'm unable to translate the syntax.

Which method would be best in terms of performance?  If I have the GIF method figured out, is it worth figuring out how to play an animation from a sprite sheet?

Context: I'm creating a loading splash screen and I'd like to play some character animations to give the screen a bit more life while loading.

Comment: Sprite sheet animations seems to be kind of "self made" animations (but Qt Quick also does them) where you paint over by yourself. Animated GIFs are very similar in this regard. So performance is probably similar, but difficult to tell without trying really. See also: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-imageelements-example.html#animatedsprite

Comment: Thanks for the insight